# Use previous data to predict next move (algorithms + statistics)

Tags: math, machine-learning, probability

Suppose the following game:

There is a person who can move in 4 directions (N, S, E and W) and there are people betting $ `X` in any of those 4 directions. When two people coincide in the direction and value bet, they take a prize.

The idea is, knowing the distribution of bets and quantities, which probabilistic model better models this situation. I had thought of Markov chains but wanted to know if there was anything more appropriate.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score 1):

If you only win money by making the same bet in the same direction as someone else, and you know the distribution of everyone else's bets, you just have to maximize your expected value... 
Let $p(x,d)$ be the probability that at least one person bets exactly $x$ dollars in direction $d$. Assuming you can only make one bet your goa is to find $\argmax_{d\in {{N,E,S,W}} \argmax_x x \cdot p(x,d) $

Answer (score 1):

If you have a *sequence* of bets, then a Markov chain is applicable.  If you have a *distribution* that applies to the upcoming round, then you have a simple maximization problem: find the bet with the highest `frequency * prize` and match that bet.

We can't help much without specifications on this "distribution".

Comment: Please edit this into your question, not a comment under an answer.  Use this general explanation and a particular situation to illustrate.